# DbContext Get<T> return dynamic table

Tags: c#, postgresql, types, dbcontext, dbset

I have a dbContext class, in which, for example, two DbSet parameters are written for working with two tables.

```
public EntityCoreContext()
{
}

public EntityCoreContext(DbContextOptions<EntityCoreContext> options)
    : base(options)
{
}

public virtual DbSet<Languages> Languages { get; set; }
public virtual DbSet<Users> Users { get; set; }
```

I know that to get data from the context I have to write: `dbContext.Users.ToList ();` or  `dbContext.Languages.ToList();`

I need to make it so that I can get data without calling directly the table by its name. From the series:
`dbContext.Get<Users>().ToList();` or `dbContext.Get<Languages>().ToList();`

Well, or in another way. So that the method that the table will be called by is universal. And supported all any table that would be passed to him.This must be done for the following methods: Insert, Update, Get, Delete.

Comment: You don't need *any* of that, as that's exactly what DbContext and DbSet are about. Those aren't tables, they are application-side entities. A DbContext isn't a connection or a model of the database, it's a Unit-of-Work. And no need for data-object-like methods, since the ORM already handles operations for multiple objects at once

Comment: The methods you want to build won't just harm performance, they are logically wrong. A DbContext is a Unit of Work so it caches modifications until it's asked to persist *all* of them. That `Insert()` you want to build can easily perform 500 DELETEs as well. Gunnar Peipman's [No need for repository or Unit of Work with Entity Framework Core](https://gunnarpeipman.com/ef-core-repository-unit-of-work/) shows how wrong this attempt is

Comment: You're trying to impose a low-level data-access-object interface on top of a high-level ORM. This is a bad idea identified as one as far back as 2009, when NHibernate made ORMs popular in .NET and *replaced* those "generic repository" interfaces. Oren Eini, the maintainer of NHibernate at the time explained this in [Repository is the new Singleton](https://ayende.com/blog/3955/repository-is-the-new-singleton)

Comment: Finally `dbContext.Get<User>()` is as hard-coded as `dbContext.Users`. You still need to know the type of the entity at compilation, but `Get<User>` won't warn you if the wrong type is used.

Comment: What is the *actual* problem you want to solve? `So that the method that the table will be called by is universal.` a DbContext is already universal. Have you encountered a specific problem and thought you need more flexibility? Trying to create a user-configurable open-ended query editor perhaps? Or a reporting query that works with every context? These can be tricky and often *not* suitable for use with an ORM. Simple CRUD though, disconnected operations, transactional changes are easy and already implemented

Answer (score 1):

In EntityFramework there exist `.Set<T>()` [method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.entity.dbcontext.set?view=entity-framework-6.2.0) wich is returning `DbSet` according to passed type.

So you could use:

```
dbContext.Set<Users>().ToList();
```

*I know it's weird naming but `Set` method here is returning `DbSet`, it's not setting anything.*

Comment: Or not use them at all, since a configured DbContext already does all that. There's no need for "dynamic" table names - there are no table names to begin with, they are application-side entities. DbContext isn't a connection or a model of the database, it's a Unit-of-Work, no need for repositories, that's what DbSet is about. And no need for single object modification methods either

Comment: And the naming isn't weird. The method is returning a Set. There are no explicit modification methods because none is needed - SaveChanges will persist all modifications

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the benefit is but something like this:

```
public IQueryable<T> GetEntity() where T : class
{
    using (EntityCoreContext ctx = new EntityCoreContext())
    {
       return ctx.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hot to use this?

Comment: Create a (helper) class that contains the GetEntity method and use it where you want. Why do you want to do it this way, if I may ask?